# Вывести заголовки из таблицы базы данных в заголовки таблицы на php

Tags: php

Как вывести данные из базы так, чтобы заголовки столбцов базы стали заголовками столбцов таблицы с помощью PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

*Предполагая, что у Вас MySQL:*

**Вариант 1:**

```
SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

*Пример:*

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database_name");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
      COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
      TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'");
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php
        while($i = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<th>'.$i["COLUMN_NAME"].'</th>';
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
    <thead>
</table>
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

*Пример:*

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database_name");
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name");
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php
        while($i = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<th>'.$i["Field"].'</th>';
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
    <thead>
</table>
```

***Документация:***

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)
- [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)